# Unexpected return value from function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

longtime lurker, first time poster.

I am writing a WEBAPI and have some questions on the default output.  I know output is based upon the ACCEPT in the request (json/xml etc).  However, I have a need to completely control the output.  I will format my own XML.

I have found several examples on how to do this, most in .cs so I am trying to change this to vb.net.

Here is one of my tests:

```
      Public Function Authenticate() As HttpResponseMessage
      Dim XML As String = "Message content"
      Return New HttpResponseMessage() With { _
      .Content = New StringContent(XML, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml") _
      }
    End Function
```

When In my calling function, when I try:
Return Authenticate()

I get an error: 
Value of type 'System.net.http.httpresponsemessage' cannot be converted to String

It seems like this is used quite a bit in .cs as I see lots of examples.  Anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this in VB.NET?

My Controller:

```
<HttpGet, HttpPost> _
Public Function [Login](<FromUri> staff As login) As String
      Dim xmlheader As String

      Dim head As New header
      xmlheader = head.addheader()

      If staff.password = "" Then
        Dim result As String
        Dim err As New messages
        result = xmlheader & err.geterror("password")
        Return Authenticate()
       End If
End Function
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you calling this in controller?

Comment: Yes, I am calling Authenticate from a contoller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is clear. YOu have

```
Public Function [Login](<FromUri> staff As login) As String
```

You need to declare your controller as

```
Public Function [Login](<FromUri> staff As login) As HttpResponseMessage
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I have been staring at that error for quite a while!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the return value from Authenticate as a string.  I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but I think `.ToString()` will work.

```
Dim foo As String = Authenticate().ToString()
' Do whatever with foo here...use it as a string
```

Comment: I am trying to take over the output from the project.  In this case, I only want the output to be "Message content" with no formatting (at this point).  Currently, I can get "message content" simply by using "Return "Message content" from my controller.  However, the actual output for XML would be <string>Message content</string>".

Comment: Using Return Authenticate.Tostring I get the project to compile, but I get:                                                        <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
}</string> as outpu..  not at all what I am wanting.  SO, I must be going about this all wrong.  My apologies for the editting, seem I can't return without saving.

Comment: Let me take an additional step back, how would I be able to stop the <string></string> form being sent with the output?